# background transparent as in the image

Tags: java, android, background, background-image, transparent

Is there a way to create a background as seen in the image?
 
[image]

Comment: Layout and widget backgrounds are transparent by default, unless differently specified.

Comment: I mean transparent as seen in the image, the chessboard one that serves to give a sense of transparency when there are elements that very probably have it.

Comment: Then it's not "transparent". That's a checkerboard. You can make a 2 by 2 squares picture. And then you'll have to tile it instead of stretching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following module, reading the readme file is very simple to use: https://github.com/duanhong169/CheckerboardDrawable